# How do I handle these exceptions so that my application doesn't crash when there is no connection?

Tags: c#, httpconnection

I have an application that connects to a server at runtime when a user tries to log in, if the server is up and the (web app) is running there is no problem but when the server is down or the (web app) that the desktop application connects to isn't running on the server the application crashes. I'm trying to catch the exceptions but the app still crashes.

```
 namespace --------
 {
 public partial class Login : MetroForm
 {
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static string token = null;
    public static long off_id = -1;

    public async void getOfficerToken(dynamic client) 
    {
        var result = await client.officers().token.Get();

        if (result.HttpResponseMessage.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(result.message.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            token = result.token;
            off_id = result.officer_id;
            this.Hide();
            Dashboard obj = new Dashboard();
            obj.Show();
        }

    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(txtUser.Text + ":" + txtPassword.Text));
            var client = new RestClient("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Authorization", "Basic " + encoded } });
            getOfficerToken(client);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            connectionlbl.Text = "There is no connection to the server.";
        }

    }

    private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ActiveControl = btnLogin;
    }
}
}
```

I get the following error:

- System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'An error occurred while sending the request.'
- InnerExceptions:
  WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server
  SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Amy I edited the question details.

Comment: Never use `async void`. Replace by `async Task`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not catching the exceptions in the right place.  Since `getOfficerToken` is `async`, here's what's happening:

1. `btnLogin_Click` is executed
2. `getOfficerToken` is `async`, so it's off running in its own thread
3. `btnLogin_Click` completes executing because it's not waiting around for `getOfficerToken` to finish because it wasnt `await`ed (okay, not really waiting around, read up on async programming to understand what's really going on)
4. The exception gets thrown in `getOfficerToken`, but `btnLogin_Click` is no longer executing so the error is not "inside" the try-catch block (overly simplistic/technically not quite correct, but you get the idea)

Short answer is also include try-catch in `getOfficerToken`, or `await` the call.

```
public async Task getOfficerToken(dynamic client) 
{
    var result = await client.officers().token.Get();

    if (result.HttpResponseMessage.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(result.message.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        token = result.token;
        off_id = result.officer_id;
        this.Hide();
        Dashboard obj = new Dashboard();
        obj.Show();
    }
}

private async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(txtUser.Text + ":" + txtPassword.Text));
        var client = new RestClient("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Authorization", "Basic " + encoded } });
        await getOfficerToken(client);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        connectionlbl.Text = "There is no connection to the server.";
    }
}
```